# html_entity_decode doesn't seem to work laravel php

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to decode html entities of some javascript code. But it doesn't seem to work, it still outputs encoded html elements. 
This %3Cscript%3 needs to become this < script >

```
    Array content

        Array
        (
            [0] => http://localhost:8888//index.php?email=%3Cscript%3Ealert%28%27biatg906op%27%29%3C%2Fscript%3E%0A
            [1] => http://localhost:8888//index.php?email=%3Cscript%3Ealert%28%22biatg906op%22%29%3C%2Fscript%3E%0A
            [2] => http://localhost:8888//index.php?email=%3CScRiPt%3Ealert%28%27biatg906op%27%29%3C%2FsCrIpT%3E%0A
            [3] => http://localhost:8888//index.php?email=%3CScRiPt%3Ealert%28%22biatg906op%22%29%3C%2FsCrIpT%3E%0A
            ...
        )

        $xss_array = explode("=", $value);

        $xss_attack = html_entity_decode($xss_array[1]);

        echo 'Attack: ' . $xss_attack.PHP_EOL;

        output
        Attack: %3Cscript%3Ealert%28%27khp9s5z73u%27%29%3C%2Fscript%3E%0A
        Attack: %3Cscript%3Ealert%28%22khp9s5z73u%22%29%3C%2Fscript%3E%0A
        Attack: %3CScRiPt%3Ealert%28%27khp9s5z73u%27%29%3C%2FsCrIpT%3E%0A
        Attack: %3CScRiPt%3Ealert%28%22khp9s5z73u%22%29%3C%2FsCrIpT%3E%0A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not html so its not decode by `html_entity_decode()`.

You can resolve it by using [urldecode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

**Code:**

```
<?php

$val= "http://localhost:8888//index.php?email=%3Cscript%3Ealert%28%27biatg906op%27%29%3C%2Fscript%3E%0A";

$xss_array = explode("=", $val);

$xss_attack = urldecode($xss_array[1]);

echo 'Attack: ' . $xss_attack.PHP_EOL;
```

**Output:**

```
Attack: <script>alert('biatg906op')</script>
```

**Demo: [Click Here](https://eval.in/847988)**

Comment: I have added demo to resolve your issue and its not related to laravel its common php issue. @melkawakibi

Answer (score 1):

that's not HTML encoding that's URL encoding, use `urldecode()` instead of html_entity_decode